# WebDav issue with Mac OS X 10.5.3 onwards

Tags: mac-osx, webdavfs

We upgraded to Mac OS X 10.5.3 and getting problem when uploading files (PUT) to a webdav server (the server is Apache running on a Windows environment). When we drag and drop on to a webdav folder using Finder we get a -36 error. When looking at the stack trace of the web server the problem is due to INVALID CRLF or some times getting the following error. Both the stack point to error when copying the stream. When googled found that it is because the Mac changed to Transfer-Encoding to 'Chunked'

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:366)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:433)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:348)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:88)
 at org.apache.commons.io.CopyUtils.copy(CopyUtils.java:200)
 at com.artesia.webdav.action.helper.ResponseWriterHelper.writeFileContentResponse(ResponseWriterHelper.java:206)
 at com.artesia.webdav.action.GetMethodAction.executeWebDavMethod(GetMethodAction.java:147)
 at com.artesia.webdav.action.BaseWebDavMethodAction.execute(BaseWebDavMethodAction.java:257)
 at com.artesia.webdav.action.BaseWebDavAction.execute(BaseWebDavAction.java:92)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
 at com.artesia.webdav.web.WebDavActionServlet.service(WebDavActionServlet.java:93)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
 at com.artesia.webdav.web.WebDavActionServlet.service(WebDavActionServlet.java:93)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
 at com.artesia.webdav.web.BaseWebDavServlet.forward(BaseWebDavServlet.java:91)
 at com.artesia.webdav.web.BaseWebDavServlet.service(BaseWebDavServlet.java:83)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
 at com.artesia.webdav.action.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:46)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
 at com.artesia.webdav.web.WebDavAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebDavAuthenticationFilter.java:463)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
 at com.artesia.webdav.web.MacSessionHackFilter.doFilter(MacSessionHackFilter.java:111)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:746)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:433)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:348)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:769)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:117)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:579)
 at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:559)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:361)
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading Mac OS X to something significantly newer - say 10.5.8?

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try running [Unix2dos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) on it, and then trying it again. Are you uploading using ASCII or Binary (I think ASCII tries to convert the line breaks automatically)